# rails render page as json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

How to render page as json correctly

my chunk of code

```
respond_to :html, :xml, :json


  def getOffersByURL
   @my_model= Mymodel.where(attr1: params[:url], :validFrom => {:$lte => Time.now}).all
   respond_with @my_model
  end
```

When in trying to do like this nothing happens

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/getOffersByURL?url=some_data.xml
```

or

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/getOffersByURL?url=some_data.json
```

concretely it comes like this

```
Processing by MyController#getOffersByURL as HTML
  Parameters: {"url"=>"some_data.xml"}
```

Comment: Can you try and check for `http://0.0.0.0:3000/getOffersByURL.json?url=some_data1`

Comment: This is working thx,but i found prettier solution add :defaults => { :format => 'json' }to my route

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your function:

```
def getOffersByURL
  @my_model= Mymodel.where(attr1: params[:url], :validFrom => {:$lte => Time.now}).all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {
        render json: @my_model
    }
    format.html {
        @my_model
    }
    end
end
```

What happens if you try to show your json like this in your view:

```
<%= @my_model.to_json %>
```

Do you have any data checking the page in the browser? Open the developers tool and try to find if the object brings any data...

Comment: Rails version 3.0 and above, the recommended syntax is what OP posted. There is no added advantage in your code, except long to type and more control in future if you wish to change something only for HTML format.